# Android opengl es 2.0 glpushmatrix, etc

Tags: android, opengl-es

I know that isnt exist pushmatrix, popmatrix, and the matrix stack, loadidentity, rotate, translate etc.

How can I rewrite my existing 1.0-1.1 engine to work with 2.0?

I tried this first:

```
void glRotate(float x, float y, float z) {
    Matrix.setRotateM(mMMatrix, 0, x, 1, 0, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mMMatrix, 0, y, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mMMatrix, 0, z, 0, 0, 1);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
}

void glTranslate(float x, float y, float z) {
    Matrix.translateM(mMMatrix, 0, x, y, z);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
}
```

glTranslate it is not working, how can I translate my modell in the world?

glRotate only rotate in Z my object, x,y doesnt work at all.

+
How to implement a matrix stack/glpush/glpopmatrix? Anybody has a shema for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use

Matrix.setIdentityM(mMMatrix, 0);

before calculating matrix transformations.

And use Matrix.rotateM() instead of Matrix.setRotateM().

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem as you about 1 year ago.

I had to write from scratch most of those functions and I can assure you it is a bloody mess and very error prone.

I suggest you to start from a very valid implementation you can find in the file "esTransform.c" in the samples directory of the OpenGL Gold Book (OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide).

The book is this one:
http://opengles-book.com/downloads.html

The code can be downloaded from google code here:
http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/

I suggest you anyway to buy the book, it becomes quickly your opengl ES 2.0 bible and it is very well done.

Just to conclude, check the usage license of the source code before you go into production.